# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I tried to replace the `Page` content using Microsoft Graph like this:

```cs
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add( some stream contents );
var formdatastream = form.ReadAsStreamAsync();
graphClient.Users[userPrincipalName]
  .Onenote
  .Pages[onenotepage.Id]
  .Content
  .Request()
  .PutAsync<OnenotePage>(formdatastream);
```

It returns `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request`, which implies that it does not accept an `HTTP PUT` request.

Clearly, [it is saying it accepts `HTTP Patch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-update-page#complete-patch-request-examples) so maybe the .Net library needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and is a result of a mismatch of the service definition and the service behavior.

If you search for 'onenoteupdatepage' in the [OneNote SDK tests](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/9304c33cfc771fe099ad00713899e6ff338781a7/tests/Microsoft.Graph.Test/Requests/Functional/OneNoteTests.cs), you can see one possible workaround for how to replace an existing page.

Comment: (MODIFIED the comment) 
Thanks Dmitry, I made it.
Even replacing a whole BODY and their objects and images with multi-part data Worked!

Comment: Lucky that even replacing the BODY itself works, although the document is saying it is not supported.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-update-page#supported-elements-and-actions

Comment: Keep in mind that there are sometimes minor differences between APIs (in this case OneNote API vs Microsoft Graph). In some cases they may be _dramatically_ different (i.e. Azure AD Graph vs Microsoft Graph) but generally they're more subtle differences (a `POST` in one being a `PUT` in another, different query parameter options available, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

To update the OneNote API, you need to trigger a PATCH request like so:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{id}/content
{JSON PAYLOAD}
```

Perhaps that's not what the SDK is doing?